# Full calendar repeat specific events for every year

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I have added full calendar with some events in my web application 
But if i add birthday event for specific date, month, year 
it will appear only for that year 
But user navigate to next year to previous year it won't show birthday event on that date

Here is my sample code

```
  <script>
  $(function () {

    /* initialize the external events
     -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    function ini_events(ele) {
      ele.each(function () {

        // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
        // it doesn't need to have a start or end
        var eventObject = {
          title: $.trim($(this).text()) // use the element's text as the event title
        }

        // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
        $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject)

        // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
        $(this).draggable({
          zIndex        : 1070,
          revert        : true, // will cause the event to go back to its
          revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
        })

      })
    }

    ini_events($('#external-events div.external-event'))

    /* initialize the calendar
     -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    //Date for the calendar events (dummy data)
    var date = new Date()
    var d    = date.getDate(),
        m    = date.getMonth(),
        y    = date.getFullYear()

    var Calendar = FullCalendar.Calendar;
    var Draggable = FullCalendarInteraction.Draggable;

    var containerEl = document.getElementById('external-events');
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('drop-remove');
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    // initialize the external events
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------

    new Draggable(containerEl, {
      itemSelector: '.external-event',
      eventData: function(eventEl) {
        console.log(eventEl);
        return {
          title: eventEl.innerText,
          backgroundColor: window.getComputedStyle( eventEl ,null).getPropertyValue('background-color'),
          borderColor: window.getComputedStyle( eventEl ,null).getPropertyValue('background-color'),
          textColor: window.getComputedStyle( eventEl ,null).getPropertyValue('color'),
        };
      }
    });

    var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
      plugins: [ 'bootstrap', 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid' ],
      header    : {
        left  : 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right : 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
      },
      'themeSystem': 'bootstrap',
      //Random default events
      events    : [
        {
          title          : 'Bday Event',
          start          : new Date(y, m, 1),
          backgroundColor: '#f56954', //red
          borderColor    : '#f56954',
          allDay:true
        },
        {
          title          : 'Long Event',
          start          : new Date(y, m, d - 5),
          end            : new Date(y, m, d - 2),
          backgroundColor: '#f39c12', //yellow
          borderColor    : '#f39c12' //yellow
        },
        {
          title          : 'Meeting',
          start          : new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
          allDay         : false,
          backgroundColor: '#0073b7', //Blue
          borderColor    : '#0073b7' //Blue
        },
        {
          title          : 'Lunch',
          start          : new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
          end            : new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
          allDay         : false,
          backgroundColor: '#00c0ef', //Info (aqua)
          borderColor    : '#00c0ef' //Info (aqua)
        }        
      ],


      editable  : true,
      droppable : true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
      drop      : function(info) {
        // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
        if (checkbox.checked) {
          // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
          info.draggedEl.parentNode.removeChild(info.draggedEl);
        }
      }    
    });

    calendar.render();
    // $('#calendar').fullCalendar()

    /* ADDING EVENTS */
    var currColor = '#3c8dbc' //Red by default
    //Color chooser button
    var colorChooser = $('#color-chooser-btn')
    $('#color-chooser > li > a').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      //Save color
      currColor = $(this).css('color')
      //Add color effect to button
      $('#add-new-event').css({
        'background-color': currColor,
        'border-color'    : currColor
      })
    })
    $('#add-new-event').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      //Get value and make sure it is not null
      var val = $('#new-event').val()
      if (val.length == 0) {
        return
      }

      //Create events
      var event = $('<div />')
      event.css({
        'background-color': currColor,
        'border-color'    : currColor,
        'color'           : '#fff'
      }).addClass('external-event')
      event.html(val)
      $('#external-events').prepend(event)

      //Add draggable funtionality
      ini_events(event)

      //Remove event from text input
      $('#new-event').val('')
    })
  })
</script>
```

Can anyone please please help me on to repeat some events for every year for specific month and date

Thank you in advance

Comment: Take a look at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/recurring-events